# Why i am getting the 'Type error' as 'tuple object is not callable'

Tags: python, tuples

```
# Predict from the test dataset
prediction1 = svn.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the accuracy
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy=(accuracy_score(y_test,prediction1)*100)
print("The accuracy in case of Supprt Vector Machine algorithm is:",accuracy)
```

The Output as

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-d206708fc3e4> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
      6 accuracy=(accuracy_score(y_test,prediction1)*100)
----> 7 print("The accuracy in case of Supprt Vector Machine algorithm is:",accuracy)

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

The output is not showing.What is the problem?

Comment: Have you used `print` as a variable name somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No i had not used 'print' as a variable

Comment: You must have. You probably mistyped `print(x,y)` as `print=(x,y)`

Comment: And if you just type `print` you'll see what the tuple is.

Comment: So I have mistakenly typed `print=('The accuracy in case of Supprt VEctor Machine algorithm is: ', accuracy)` , previously but after changin it to `print('The accuracy in case of Supprt Vector Machine algorithm is: ', accuracy)` `` it is not working also, why ?